# Rear Shock Size for Felt Virtue 1 2008

Tags: full-suspension

I have just bought a 2008 Felt Virtue 1 frame and have no idea of the size of shock I need. Measuring the eye-to-eye length, it looks like 185mm, but how can I work out the stroke length?

Comment: You’ll likely want to contact the manufacturer for this info.

Comment: Do you have the original shock to measure from?

Comment: You could let all of the air out, compress the shock, measure the (compressed) eye-to-eye length, and subtract that from the extended e2e

Answer (score 1):

The [spec page on BikePedia](https://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?item=14064) says the rear shock is "Fox Float R Air, 130mm travel" and the fork is "RockShox Recon 351 Air, 80 - 130mm adjustable travel".

Unfortunately it appears that Felt doesn't have information on bike previous to 2010 on their [archive page](https://feltbicycles.com/pages/archived-bikes).

Comment: Yes. its the eye-to-eye length and the stroke length I'm struggling to find.

Comment: OP is not the only rider with this question   https://www.mtbr.com/threads/felt-virtue-1-2008-shock-dimensions.1151585/

Comment: Does a side-photo of an assembled bike give any clues?   https://ep1.pinkbike.org/p6pb16381254/p6pb16381254.jpg  shows a Fox shock in an unloaded state, so presumably its original.   Ratioing it off the 559mm BSD rear wheel suggests the shock is  2 5/8 of the wheel, or 212mm eye to eye in the relaxed state.    Find more action photos of the bike and that might help calculating the shortened length?    ideally these numbers need verifying by some other method too.